# Set background image height to viewport height

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

In my `Nuxt.js` application using `Vuetify.js`, I want to set a background image for the whole content:

```html
    <v-content>
      <v-img
        src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/500/300"
      >
        <v-container justify-center fill-height>
          <v-row justify="center" align="center">
            <v-col cols="12">
              <nuxt />
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-img>
    </v-content>
```

The problem is that the content is not centered vertically because the image takes the full height of the window, thus I need to scroll down to see the content.

Is there a way to set the image's height to exactly that of the viewport's height in order to see my content centered vertically and the window does not net scroll down because of the image ?

If the content of the page is long, I should be able to scroll down and still see the image set as the background of the page

Minimalist [demo code](https://github.com/begueradj/nuxt-vuetify-play) on Github in case you have time to run it.

Comment: I could try to help but please provide some online fiddle etc so we do not have to clone repo etc.

Comment: I understand, but for this particular example, I can not reproduce it on Codepen, for example

Comment: why? It will work the same within SPA

Answer (score 2):

Not really a vue-javascript solution but a CSS one. The following setup will result in a fullpage background image and the content being vertically aligned without a scrollbar.

EDIT: Use static asset

In your template:

```
<v-content 
  :style="`background-image: url(${require('../assets/image.jpg')})`" 
  class="fill-height bg-image">
  <v-container justify-center fill-height>
    <v-row justify="center" align="center">
      <v-col cols="12" justify="center" style="border: 1px solid;">
        <nuxt />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

And in your styles:

```
<style>
 .bg-image {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Your solution is as good as the one I accepted. Hope it is Ok if I accept the other one because it suits better what I have in my real application where I have the image in the **static** folder. +1

Comment: Sure. Where did you add the 100vh though? Usually 100vh would still leave a scrollbar because of the appbar on top. Oh if you want a static asset you just need to assign the background-css with :style directly in the vue-template and not in <styles>.

Comment: I did this: `<v-img :src="myImage" height="100vh"`> ... other components ...</v-img>` The scrholls disappeared. Note that in my real application, I did this in **layouts/default.vue** file

Comment: Thank you so much for the information through your post and comment

Comment: Interesting. I cloned your repo and the `height="100vh"` on v-img won't work for me. I still have a scrollbar. But if it works for you then the issue is solved :)

Comment: That is good you told me about it. But I do not know why it worked in my case without the scroll bar. If later I see a weird behavior, I will choose your solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Height:100vh maybe?

vw  Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport*
vh  Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: I noticed your solution works but when the content of my page is longer, I can not scroll down to read the content while the image is set as the background